# Creating a view with constant text column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Easy question I can't seem to find an easy answer to. Why, in MSSQL, can't I create a " " and a "CONSTANT_TEXT_VALUE" column in the view below? There should be a way of doing this right?

```
CREATE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS
SELECT DEPT,
SALES,
"" AS BLANK_COLUMN,
"Some Text" AS CONSTANT_TEXT_VALUE
FROM SOME_TABLE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text delimiter in SQL Server follows the ANSI standard.  It is a single quote:

```
CREATE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS
    SELECT DEPT, SALES,
           '' AS BLANK_COLUMN, 'Some Text' AS CONSTANT_TEXT_VALUE
    FROM SOME_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `single quote`s.

```
CREATE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS
SELECT DEPT,
SALES,
' ' AS BLANK_COLUMN,
'Some Text' AS CONSTANT_TEXT_VALUE
FROM SOME_TABLE
```